# how to integrate Blogs in sharepoint custom site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, blogs

in my sharepoint site, I
need to integrate blogs.

can any one give me help with this?

Integrating Blog in SharePoint site

my sharepoint site Custom site Definition i am selecting custom site template

Answer (score 0):

Under **Site Actions** for a WSS 3.0 site, select "**Create**". Under Web Pages, **click Sites and Workspaces**. Under the Collaboration tab, you will find the Blog option.